# ReactJS | Как передать функции аргумент как объект события?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, аргументы

Допустим у меня есть `<button id='1'/>` (id = 1..9), и у меня есть какая-либо функция. Я к тэгу `button` добавляю атрибут `onClick`, и вписываю её значение имя функции. Моя функция принимает аргумент `btn`, у которого я вывожу в консоль значение `id`. Но пишет `underfined`. Как мне передать для функции аргумент `this`?

Если не понятно, то как мне на **ReactJS** сделать `<button id=1..9 onclick="Foo(this)"/>`?

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите про передачу параметров - https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ прост:

```
<button onClick={Foo}></button>
```

```js
const Foo = e => {...}
```